# Dealing with imbalanced datasets for a case-control study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, unbalanced-classes

I'm working with a dataset where the number of samples in my positive class is significantly lower than the negative class (e.g., 30 positive samples and 160 negative samples).
I am planning to compare means between these two groups, but I am aware that the imbalanced nature might result in lower statistical power.
Are there any specific strategies or adjustments to improve the power of statistical tests in the context of imbalanced datasets?
Would it be acceptable to shrink the size of the negative samples, e.g. performing an exact-matching procedure, or am I just trowing away good data?

Comment: Informally, the way I think of it is that, if you had the opportunity to allocate 190 subjects between positive and negative, a 95/95 split would be ideal, but 30/160 is better than 30/159 or 30/30.

Comment: do you suggest me to use a mann-whitney test even if the variables are continuous and normally distributed?

Comment: That's a separate question and a dicey issue, but I marked this as a duplicate for the general sense in that linked answer that 95/95 would be ideal, but 30/160 is better than 30/159 or 30/30.